# How do I get the value from [object Object] on event change

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

[image]On event change I'm trying to capture the value of an object that's displayed in a select drop down.

```html
<ion-select
  placeholder="Select your itinerary"
  (ionChange)="handleChange($event)"
  (ionCancel)="pushLog('ionCancel fired')"
  (ionDismiss)="pushLog('ionDismiss fired')">
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let itinerary of myItineraries" value="{{itinerary?.itinerary}}">{{itinerary?.itinerary.destination}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

There are several properties in itinerary that I need but I'm only displaying the destination.  However, I need those other properties on event change.

However, when I attempt to capture the change I'm only getting [Object object].

```
handleChange(e) {
  console.log('event', e.target);
  this.pushLog('ionChange fired with value: ' + e.detail.value);
}
```

and this is the console.log:

> ionChange fired with value: '[Object object]

After searching online I've tried using `JSON.stringify(e.detail.value)` simply gives me `"[Object object]"`

How do I get the actual values of the object's other properties?

Comment: if `JSON.stringify(e.detail.value)` gives you `"[Object object]"`... It's because it already is a string. Then the issue is when the `e.detail.value` is assigned something. to prove that, try `typeof(e.detail.value)`.

Comment: You're right...it gives me a string.  So how do I get the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an object (or array) instead of a string as the value, you'd need to set it like this: `[value]="itinerary?.itinerary"`:

```
<ion-select
  placeholder="Select your itinerary"
  (ionChange)="handleChange($event)"
  (ionCancel)="pushLog('ionCancel fired')"
  (ionDismiss)="pushLog('ionDismiss fired')">
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let itinerary of myItineraries" [value]="itinerary?.itinerary">
    {{ itinerary?.itinerary.destination }}
  </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Then in the component's code, you can get the selected value like this:

```
handleChange(e) {
  console.log(e.detail.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't like this solution but it works.  I get the other propery values by referencing them in the html:

```js
const test = e.detail.value.split("*");
    console.log('event', test);
    this.pushLog('ionChange fired with value: ' + test);
```

```html
value="{{itinerary?.itinerary.destination}}, * {{itinerary?.itinerary.moreProperties}}"
```

The event has all of the different values in one string that I have to split.

I don't like this because it pollutes the html, and I have to use * to separate the string and I'm not 100% the order will stay the same.  I have to assume the order won't change and I'll never have "*" in any of the other property fields.  There's got to be a better way to do this.

Comment: So it does not work using `JSON.stringify` in the `value=` attribute? Or you did not even try?

Comment: It does not work.  It just outputs "[Object object]"